# Error in for-each about XSL conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

I got a question about XSL and XML.
I need to write '1' and '2' in the following example:

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="bodytext/artigo">
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="@tip = '1'">
   <h2>1</h2>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="@tip = '2'">
   <h2>2</h2>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
  <h2>3</h2>
 </xsl:otherwise>
```

XML:

```
<utilizador>Manuel</utilizador>
<sex>M</sex>
<artigo tip='1'>
    <nome>A Mentira Sagrada</nome>
    <price>12.99</price>
    <iva>23 %</iva>
    <link>9c6af52790</link>
</artigo>
<artigo tip='2'>
    <nome>A Mentira Sagrada</nome>
    <price>12.99</price>
    <iva>23 %</iva>
    <link>u8Jp06blGQkKxdEbkoT0</link>
</artigo>
```

I got only printed '1' and I need to be printed '1' and '2'.

Extra Information:
I understand right now the problem is related with '&' sign. If I had the below XML with '&' sign it doesn't work. If I remove it works but I needed it.

```
<bodytext>
    <utilizador>Criador Intelectual</utilizador>
    <sex>M</sex>
 <artigo tip='1'>
        <nome>A Mentira Sagrada</nome>
        <price>12.99</price>
        <iva>23 %</iva>
        <link>http://q-ebooks.com.pt/fulfillment/URLLink.acsm?action=enterorder&</link>
     </artigo>
 <artigo tip='2'>
        <nome>A Mentira Sagrada</nome>
        <price>12.99</price>
        <iva>23 %</iva>
        <link>teste2</link>
     </artigo>
</bodytext>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here.  Can you post more of the code?  You've left out the "bodytext" element.

Comment: I edited the post right now. See it please.

Comment: If your input document contains a bare `&` (i.e. one that is not escaped as `&amp;`) then it's not well-formed XML and I would expect the transformation to fail.

Comment: &amp; doesn't work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include your entire input XML file (or the smallest subset of which exhibits the unexpected behavior).  Without knowing the input file, here's a shot in the dark: Try changing your XPath to include all artigo elements as a sanity check:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//artigo">
...
```

If this results in more than just '1' being printed, we can then help you tighten-up the XPath as necessary (but please include more of the XML input file).

**Per update of question**:  Use `&amp;` instead of '&'.  A raw '&' cannot be used in XML because it normally serves to introduce an entity.  To escape this use and include an actual ampersand, use `&amp;` instead.

**Per second update of question**:  Let's look at the big picture:

**This XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="bodytext/artigo">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@tip = '1'">
            <h2>1</h2>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@tip = '2'">
            <h2>2</h2>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <h2>3</h2>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to this input XML file:**

```
<bodytext>
  <utilizador>Criador Intelectual</utilizador>
  <sex>M</sex>
  <artigo tip='1'>
    <nome>A Mentira Sagrada</nome>
    <price>12.99</price>
    <iva>23 %</iva>
    <link>http://q-ebooks.com.pt/fulfillment/URLLink.acsm?action=enterorder&amp;</link>
  </artigo>
  <artigo tip='2'>
    <nome>A Mentira Sagrada</nome>
    <price>12.99</price>
    <iva>23 %</iva>
    <link>teste2</link>
  </artigo>
</bodytext>
```

**Yields this output file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <h2>1</h2>
   <h2>2</h2>
</root>
```

Comment: What I mean is that if I run it like this "<link>http://q-ebooks.com.pt/fulfillment/URLLink.acsm?action=enterorder&</link>" it does not work. If I run it like "<link>http://q-ebooks.com.pt/fulfillment/URLLink.acsm?action=enterorder</link>" it works. I only remove & sign.

Comment: I got no errors, it's only printed '1' and I want '1' and '2' to be printed. Sorry for the messy problem.

Comment: What tool do you use? Thanks

Comment: Tool recommendations are out of scope for Stack Overflow, and this issue is well above a tool version dependency.  (But, FWIW, that output was from SaxonHE9-5-1-2J; I also Saxon PE for certain projects but routinely prefer HE for answering questions.)